# How to disable DidSelect being called for some part of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Since my cell is expandable on tap and contains two buttons in the expandable part, I'd like to make DidSelect/ DidDeselect not being callled when user taps around these button to improve UX.

The buttons are placed inside StackView inside another UIView.

[image]

I tried disabling userInteraction for both stackView and UIView container but result is the same.

What would you recommend to disable entire UIView container (note this is a part of my cell) from calling DidSelect/ DidDeselect on tap?

Comment: Disable selection altogether and implement selection in the cell itself, only in the parts you wish selectable.

Comment: you can put these buttons on another view which is larger in size.

Comment: @vaibhav they are already put in view, see the image of view hierarchy above

Comment: have you tried by implementing the actions of these two buttons? Whenever you tap on these buttons their respective action method will call, not didSelect or didDeSelect methods.

Comment: @vaibhav I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @DCDC, please check ans.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement the actions of these two buttons inside `stackView`.

```
// inside cellForRowAt indexPath
cell?.button1.tag = indexPath.row
cell?.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(defineTypeAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

Respective Action:

```
func defineTypeAction (_ sender: UIButton){
    let alert=UIAlertController(title: kAppName, message: "Select", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
        sender.setTitle("your title", for: .normal)
        // your custom code
    }));

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When you tap on button their action method will be called instead of `tableView` delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have no idea how this answer relates to disabling DidSelect called on some part of TableViewCell

Comment: you cannot disable the delegate method of `tableView` if you implemented those, you would only be able to assign the button target in order to prevent `didSelect` method call.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

The basic way to accomplish that is interrupting the tableview tap gesture with another tap gesture recognizer.

If you have a custom view in your cell just add a gesture recognizer to your view.

```
@objc func handleTouch(){
    print("Table view interrupted")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTouch))
    interruptView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

If you don't create a custom view just implement these methods for any view (interruptView) in your custom cell.